# Change the display of error messages in parsley

Tags: validation, parsley.js

I'd like to change the positioning of the default Parsley error messages, which are displayed at the bottom of each element during validation. I want them to remain at the bottom but with a larger left-margin. I tried altering the CSS file; i was able to change the color of the messages but the left-margin becomes static at some point, no matter what value i use. 
I've gone through the documentation but still having issues with how i can do this. How do i customize the display of my error messages? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
.parsley-required{
margin-left:20px;
}
```

works for me.  Can you use your browsers inspector to check that the css is being applied?